# Debugging SCons

Tags: python, debugging, trace, scons, circular-dependency

I've written a rather complicated set of SCons scripts, and I have some errors I cannot find, for example intermediate files are removed or there are cyclic dependencies reported, and I want to know the reason. Unfortunately, I don't see any means to get good verbose debugging output of what SCons is doing and where. For example, the option `--taskmastertrace=FILE` does not explain why my intermediate files were deleted. (EDIT: of course I can protect them using `Precious`, but those files are *needed* for another target and the build fails -- I just don't see why they are deleted. My current solution involves `Precious`, but it's not a real fix for the issue).

I'd like to get a trace of everything going on, including dependency changes, file creations and deletions, and other operations. Is there any way to enable such verbose logging? I'm a little stuck with my project currently.

Cheers,
H.

Comment: Why didn't [tree](http://www.scons.org/doc/0.98.5/HTML/scons-user/x3520.html) option work for you: `scons -nQ --tree=status yourfile`.

Comment: Whatever reason, but the intermediate file does not appear in the tree. That's one of the things I'm wondering about.

Comment: I agree with you that the main deficiency to scons is being able to debug stuff.  I with they would just add a logging feature.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved the problem. It seems the reason was that a directory slipped into the list of targets, and directories create their own set of implicit dependencies. At least that's what I think, because after removing the directory the scripts work as expected. Can anyone clarify if my assumption is correct?

I still don't know exactly as to how debug SCons with more details, my solution was to add function decorators to `/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py` that dump function calls + arguments and return values.

Comment: I can confirm that adding a Dir as a target will have odd effects.  If the directory already exists, the dependency passes and no build occurs.  Much better by far to depend on an actual file in the directory.